# DalekJS: test hangs after running execute()

Tags: dalekjs

Is there another way to collect user input than using execute() to run a prompt command, or how do I get the code to continue running after prompting the user for input?  Right now it lets me enter a search term but doesn't open the web site; the test just hangs and I have to enter ctrl-C to exit.

Running Browser: Google Chrome
OS: Mac OS X 10.8.5 x86_64
Browser Version: 36.0.1985.125
DalekJS CLI Tools Version: 0.0.4
DalekJS  local install: 0.0.8

```
module.exports = {
```

'Header Search Results': function (test) {
    test
        .execute(function() {
            var searchTerm = prompt('Please enter a known search term');
        })
        .open(myURL)

```
    [a bunch of other steps that work fine when I hardcode a searchTerm; i.e, omit the prompt]

    .done();
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Currently when Dalek hangs, it probably means that something has error'erd out and the test cannot proceed. This behaviour can be misleading in making you think that the tests are taking a bit of time to run when that is not the case - I've created a [ticket](https://github.com/dalekjs/dalek/issues/118) about this here.

Now on the other hand, I would get you to reconsider the idea of prompting user input when running a Dalek test. What you should be doing is scripting Dalek tests that run with known static data, and script all your tests with any input parameters in your tests.

Can you share what is it that you are testing?